# Decrypting Two Variables Using crypto.createDecipheriv in Node.js

Tags: node.js

**Am trying to Decipheriv two variables in crypto npm**, but its not wokring, i get this error message : (Assignment to constant variable).
its working fine when i try to decipheriv a single varaible.

```
            const user = await User.findById(userId);
            const cipheremail = user.email;
            const ciphernumber = user.mobile;
            const key = config.key;
            const iv = config.iv;

            const decipheremail = await crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', key, iv);
            decipheremail += await decipheremail.update(cipheremail, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipheremail.final('utf8');

            const deciphernumber = await crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', key, iv);
            deciphernumber += await deciphernumber.update(ciphernumber, 'hex', 'utf8') + deciphernumber.final('utf8');

            console.log("EMAIL: " + decipheremail)
            console.log("NUMBER: " + deciphernumber)

            
            const decipherdata = [deciphernumber, decipheremail];
            return decipherdata;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("FROM deciipher");
            console.log(error.message);
        }
```

Comment: **Assignment to constant variable** is the problem, that means you can not reassign a value to a `const` variable, replace `const decipheremail` with `let decipheremail` and similarly `const deciphernumber` with `let deciphernumber`. you can learn more about `+=` [Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) here